# How to retrieve an array data from firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

hi i have an firebase as a back end for my flutter app and i can read and write data fine but i can not retrieve an array of strings when i put it in a text widget and add the .toString() parameter it retrieves it but in unpresentable way i want to view it in a list view can anybody help.

this is my code

```js
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 5, left: 5),
                    child: Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      elevation: 9,
                      color: Theme.of(context).cardColor.withOpacity(.95),
                      shadowColor:
                          Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(.5),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: 10, right: 10, left: 10, top: 15),
                        height: 230,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF0B0F1B),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 1, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'members :-' +
                                    snapshot.data.documents[i].data['members']
                                        .toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'amount :-' +
                                    snapshot
                                        .data.documents[i].data['amount'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your snapshot is not a stream then await the request and store it in a local variable. Else, Make use of a stream builder widget

Comment: it is a stream and the problem is not the snapshot,from my code snippet the snapshot value members is an array if firebase so what i wanted is to display the values in that array in a listview

Comment: Instead of using a list view builder, make use of a Stream builder.